# How to query Data Group by with Order by in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have sample data like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (aktif, "START", "END", NO_BOX, QTY) AS
SELECT 1, 'A0001', 'A0020', 2016, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A0021', 'A0040', 2016, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A0041', 'A0060', 2016, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'A0061', 'A0080', NULL, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'A0081', 'A0100', NULL, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A0101', 'A0120', 2016, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A0121', 'A0140', 2016, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A0141', 'A0160', 2016, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'A0161', 'A0180', NULL, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'A0181', 'A0200', NULL, 100 FROM DUAL;
```

I want to group by the columns where `AKTIF` and `NO_BOX` remain the same based on the order of the rows and then select `SUM(QTY)`, `MIN(START)`, `MAX(END)`.

The output should be:

| AKTIF | START | END | NO_BOX | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A0001 | A0060 | 2016 | 300 |
| 0 | A0061 | A0100 | NULL | 200 |
| 1 | A0101 | A0160 | 2016 | 300 |
| 0 | A0161 | A0200 | NULL | 200 |

Comment: what have you attempted? What is the logic?

Comment: Showing desired results isn't always very clear.  If you can write out what the logic is that you want to implement, that will help get better answers. It may also help you figure it out for yourself.

Comment: I have tried to Group by on Column "AKTIF" and "NO_BOX", then on the Select i SUM(QTY), MIN(START), MAX(END). But the result is AKTIF = 0 become 1. 
I want to group the Data based on the Order by.

Sorry my English is bad

Comment: what do you mean " based on the Order by"  grouping has nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: From Oracle 12, you would want to use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2c17559f152af0999f031083904be7c6)

Comment: thanks, @MT0 has modified my question. and your example worked, I really thank you so Much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, that's gaps and islands problem.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (aktif, cstart, end, no_box, qty) as
  2    (select 1, 'A0001', 'A0020', 2016, 100 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'A0021', 'A0040', 2016, 100 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'A0041', 'A0060', 2016, 100 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 0, 'A0061', 'A0080', null, 100 from dual union all
  7     select 0, 'A0081', 'A0100', null, 100 from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 1, 'A0101', 'A0120', 2016, 100 from dual union all
 10     select 1, 'A0121', 'A0140', 2016, 100 from dual union all
 11     select 1, 'A0141', 'A0160', 2016, 100 from dual union all
 12     --
 13     select 0, 'A0161', 'A0180', null, 100 from dual union all
 14     select 0, 'A0181', 'A0200', null, 100 from dual
 15    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 16  temp as
 17    (select t.*,
 18       row_number() over (order by cstart) -
 19       row_Number() over (partition by aktif order by cstart) grp
 20     from test t
 21    )
 22  select aktif,
 23    min(cstart) cstart,
 24    max(end) end,
 25    no_box,
 26    sum(qty) qty
 27  from temp
 28  group by aktif, no_box, grp
 29  order by cstart;

     AKTIF CSTAR END       NO_BOX        QTY
---------- ----- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 A0001 A0060       2016        300
         0 A0061 A0100                   200
         1 A0101 A0160       2016        300
         0 A0161 A0200                   200

SQL>
```